# BUILD FAILURE in installing maven plug in

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I am trying to build an android application project using maven and eclipse.

I created a 'hello world' file and then converted it into a maven project. After adding com.google.android dependency and android-maven-plugin 3.5.3, when I run the project as Build Maven by setting the goal as android:apk, I am getting the following error -

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Final_Maven1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.3:apk (default-cli) @ Final_Maven1 ---
[INFO] Copying local assets files to combined assets directory.
[INFO] Enabling debug build for apk.
[INFO] /home/developer/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools/aapt [package, -f, -M, /home/developer/Final_Maven/AndroidManifest.xml, -S, /home/developer/Final_Maven/res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, /home/developer/Final_Maven/target/generated-sources/combined-assets/assets, -I, /home/developer/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar, -F, /home/developer/Final_Maven/target/Final_Maven1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ap_, --debug-mode]
[INFO] /home/developer/Final_Maven/res/values-v11/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[INFO] /home/developer/Final_Maven/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.042s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 21 16:13:19 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/104M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.3:apk (default-cli) on project Final_Maven1: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /home/developer/Final_Maven && /home/developer/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools/aapt package -f -M /home/developer/Final_Maven/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/developer/Final_Maven/res --auto-add-overlay -A /home/developer/Final_Maven/target/generated-sources/combined-assets/assets -I /home/developer/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar -F /home/developer/Final_Maven/target/Final_Maven1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ap_ --debug-mode, Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the `following articles:`
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What is your API level? Show your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to follow the instructions on [maven-android-plugin issue 379](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=379) to workaround a similar problem. Which suggests swapping to 3.6.0+ of the maven-android-plugin should also work?

For the record, the fix is to run the following commands:

```
cd <android-sdk>/platform-tools
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aapt aapt
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/lib lib
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aidl aidl
```